# Call to a member function update() on null in laravel 9

Tags: laravel-8

What is wrong with this function? I ve got error on this line:

```
$bookShelf->update($request->all());
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\BookShelf;
use App\Models\Book;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreBookShelfRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateBookShelfRequest;

class BookShelfController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $bookshelves = BookShelf::with('book')->latest()->get();
    // $bookshelves = BookShelf::all();
    $model = new BookShelf();
    $books = Book::with('category')->latest()->get();
    // $books = Book::all();
    $categories = Category::with(['users.books.shelf']);
    return view('admin.bookshelves.index', compact('bookshelves', 'books', 'model', 'categories'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $model = new BookShelf;
    $categories = Category::all();
    $books = Book::with('category')->latest()->get();
    return view('admin.bookshelves.create', compact('categories', 'model', 'books'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreBookShelfRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(StoreBookShelfRequest $request)
{
    BookShelf::create($request->all());
    return redirect('admin_area/shelves')->with('success', 'Selamat Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\BookShelf  $bookShelf
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(BookShelf $bookShelf)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\BookShelf  $bookShelf
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($shelf_code)
{
    $model = BookShelf::find($shelf_code);
    $categories = Category::all();
    $books = Book::with('category')->latest()->get();
    return view('admin.bookshelves.edit', compact('categories', 'model', 'books'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\UpdateBookShelfRequest  $request
 * @param  \App\Models\BookShelf  $bookShelf
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(UpdateBookShelfRequest $request, BookShelf $bookShelf)
{
    $bookShelf = BookShelf::find($bookShelf->shelfcode);
    $bookShelf->update($request->all());

    return redirect('admin_area/bookshelves')->with('success', 'Selamat Data Berhasil Di Ubah');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\BookShelf  $bookShelf
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(BookShelf $bookShelf, $id)
{
    $bookShelf = BookShelf::find($id);
    $bookShelf->delete();
    return redirect('admin_area/shelves')->with('success', "Data berhasil disimpan");
}


}
```

My Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BookShelf extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $load = ['category', 'book'];

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'shelfcode';
}
}
```

My Edit View

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Edit Data Buku')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-9 justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="m-0">Edit Data Rak Buku</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="card-title"></h6>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('shelves.update', $model->shelfcode) }}"
                            enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            {{-- <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"> --}}
                            @method('PUT')
                            @include('admin.bookshelves.form')
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-save">
                                    <span class="fas fa-edit"> Edit Data Buku</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        {{-- @endsection --}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're querying your `BookShelf` model by the wrong key. You can also remove `$bookShelf = BookShelf::find($bookShelf->shelfcode);` from the `update` function since it is already injected by the framework when you use model binding (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding).

Answer (score 0):

When you have this common error, there is no trap, it litteraly means that you are trying to call `update` on `null`.

It's **exactly** like doing `null->update($request->all())` (and you can try, you'll have the same error).

The only explanation here is that `$bookShelf = BookShelf::find($bookShelf->shelfcode);` returns `null`.

Regarding the structure itself,

```php
public function update(UpdateBookShelfRequest $request, BookShelf $bookShelf)
{
    $bookShelf = BookShelf::find($bookShelf->shelfcode);
//...
}
```

makes no sense since the whole purpose of using implicit route binding is to avoid the manual query you are making to retrieve `$bookShelf`. It should already be the `BookShelf` you need.